# How simplify my request code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ienumerable, html.dropdownlistfor

I use this part of code to get informations from my database, using Entity Framework, and add all of it in a IEnumerable property for, at the end, a DropDownListFor display.
I need to use that kind a code many time so I would like to make it the most powerfull at the begenning.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Functions { get
    {
        List<SelectListItem> result = new List<SelectListItem>();
        using (followupconsultantEntities dataModel = new followupconsultantEntities())
        {
            var myEvents = from e in dataModel.functions
                           select e;
            foreach (var function in myEvents)
            {
                SelectListItem myList = new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Value = function.ID_Function.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                                Text = function.FU_Name
                                            };
                result.Add(myList);
            }
        }
        return result;
    } }
```

Thanks for help

The view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFunction,Model.Functions) %>
</div>
```

For information, my controller:

```
public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;
        return View(new RegisterModel());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using **[System.Web.Mvc.SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)**.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Functions { get
{
    using (followupconsultantEntities dataModel = new followupconsultantEntities())
    {
        return new SelectList(dataModel.functions.ToArray(), "ID_Function", "FU_Name");
    }
}
```

Also consider **[AutoMapper](http://automapper.org)**.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code work like mine so it was what I want but, a error occured about a System.ObjectDisposedException with the view. I edit the post for showing you the view and the controller.

What kind of change may I do?

Comment: @ArnaudBessems You will have to retrieve your `functions` data inside the `using` block. The way it is written at the moment you won't actually attempt to fetch the data until it's rendering in the view and by that time your context would have been disposed.

Comment: You need to iterate through IQueriable before closing context. So You need to use dataModel.functions.ToArray()

Comment: Thanks Kirill, it's fixed the issue.
Thanks all for the answers !

Comment: It is not most effective because it get from database not only ID_Function and FU_Name columns but all other columns. You can see my answer below how to improve request.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. In this code you will not get from database data that you not need.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Functions { get
{
    using (followupconsultantEntities dataModel = new followupconsultantEntities())
    {
        return new SelectList(dataModel.functions.Select(f=>
               new 
               {
                   Value = function.ID_Function.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                   Text = function.FU_Name
               })
               .ToArray(), "Value", "Text");
   }
```

}

Comment: This code will not work, as you're trying to map `"ID_Function"` and `"FU_Name"` strings to `Value` and `Text` properties.